# My .htaccess file doesn't work. Do i have an error?

Tags: .htaccess

In the code above are the lines that i have in my .htaccess file. The problem is when is a single command works like a charm but when i add many commands doesnt work any of thems. Please can anyone help me to find the error.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.marinoswood.gr$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.marinoswood.gr/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^185\.4\.133\.44
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.marinoswood.gr/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on

    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few rules of thumb:

1. Always put your redirect rules **before** any internal rewrite rules, so anything with an `R` flag must be first
2. If you are using the `F` flag, in a rule to block access, those rules must be **before** all rules, including your redirect rules (ones with `R` flag)
3. Rewrite conditions only apply to the **immediately following rule**, so if the conditions need to be applied to multiple rules, those conditions must be repeated for each of them
4. Those `.php` rules are completely broken and need to be rewritten

Additionally, the mod_expires directives do not impact the rules.

So maybe you want something like?:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.marinoswood.gr$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.marinoswood.gr/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^185\.4\.133\.44
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.marinoswood.gr/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php [L]


<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on

    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you bro, your answer and advices is very helpful